# Access Report not display data from data source

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have built access report, when I bind to one specific column then whole report is not displaying data but when i change to another field, report is working fine. I check the datasource and it is displaying the data fine in query result (table view).
Following is query that is used as datasource:[image: query with problematic column highlighted]

table view of query:
[image: data]

and report view when field is set to problematic column:[image: report]

and report when field is set to random column:
[image: report with random column]

Design view of report:
[image: design view of report]

Comment: @Tester field which is causing problem is of datatype "longText" and rest of fields are either "short or date type". Incase you need any further infomation that will help you to understand problem better, let me know.

Comment: @Tester what do you mean by more details? please before writing a comment read the details of question.

Comment: @HousseinZouari This question provides very few details. It should include an [mcve], currently it provides no way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth i added few more details. Incase you need any further information, kindly let me know

Comment: Why are you using alias for memBermerkungan field that is the same as the field name? Using aliases for natural fields is totally unnecessary and just makes the SQL longer.

Comment: @June7 I was trying different things  like using different columns as in place of memBermerkungen and when i switch back to original filed i forget to remove it.

Comment: I did test in my db doing that same calc on a memo field and do not have issue. Cannot replicate the problem.

Comment: @June7 one thing i forget to mention that tables are link tables. Can it be a reason? because as per my understanding if it is  showing data in the tableview i don't think ther should be a problem in displaying it. Also i copied i value from column and hardcode it in select statement and gave the alias it is working fine but same value.text when return from query its not displaying.... any kind of suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: Linked tables should not be issue. Yes, if it shows in datasheet view should display in report. Since cannot replicate issue, cannot advise solution. Would have to view db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187933/discussion-between-maqsood-and-june7).

Comment: Does the report have sorting and grouping? If so, please disclose them